# Oracle merge statement ORA-30926 error

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

please help me rectify the following error

```
    MERGE INTO TBL_SERIAL_NUMBER_MASTER A
USING
( SELECT DISTINCT (SERIAL_NUMBER), FNN, HOST_NAME   FROM TBL_INVENTORY 
WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL) B
ON (A.SERIAL_NUMBER = B.SERIAL_NUMBER)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET 
  A.DEVICE_FNN = B.FNN,
  A.VALID = 'Valid',
  A.HOST_NAME = B.HOST_NAME,
  A.CHASSIS_MODULE = 'Chassis',
  A.SN_SUPDATE_SOURCE = 'Inventory Master',
  A.HOST_NAME_UPDATE_SOURCE = 'Inventory Master'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (A.SERIAL_NUMBER, A.DEVICE_FNN, A.VALID, A.HOST_NAME, A.CHASSIS_MODULE, A.SN_SUPDATE_SOURCE, A.HOST_NAME_UPDATE_SOURCE)
  VALUES (B.SERIAL_NUMBER, B.FNN, 'Valid', B.HOST_NAME, 'Chassis', 'Inventory Master', 'Inventory Master'); 
COMMIT;
```

**Error Report** -

> SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source
>   tables
>   30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
>
> Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
>              activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
>
> Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml. 54,149 rows merged.

Comment: you are not selecting the unique records in the USING clause.use the appropriate ON clause condition.The statement is not able to find one single row that it can match with.

Comment: provide me with sample data if possible